# How do i get a css html menu dropdown like this picture

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

How do i get a good or similar HTML/CSS drop down like this picture
http://i65.tinypic.com/2s8sc4j.png

I have this code in my style.php

```css
/*----- Toggle Button -----*/

.toggle-nav {
  display: none;
}


/*----- Menu -----*/

@media screen and (min-width: 860px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #303030;
  }
}

.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.menu a {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #777;
  transition: color linear 0.15s;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu .current-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #66a992;
}


/*----- Search -----*/

.search-form {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.search-form input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form button {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 7px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  background: #66a992;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
}


/*----- Responsive -----*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
  .search-form input {
    width: 120px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .menu ul.active {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120%;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #303030;
  }
  .menu ul:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 22px;
    content: '';
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #303030;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #303030;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #777;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: color linear 0.15s;
  }
  .toggle-nav:hover,
  .toggle-nav.active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #66a992;
  }
  .search-form {
    margin: 12px 0px 0px 20px;
    float: left;
  }
  .search-form input {
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="active">
    <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul> <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>
  <form class="search-form">
    <input type="text">
    <button>Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

The results of my code look like:
http://i67.tinypic.com/qp1l5d.png

The drop down menu is not opening on click. Can I achieve it or get a similar CSS/HTML menu drop down like the picture above?
Big thanks for your time and contribution is my solutions

Comment: How can one read that CSS without mistakes...
Can you provide a jsFiddle ... those tinypic links are popping spam.

Comment: Where the hell are you debugging? It seems like a phone from the 90's

Comment: This is a fiddle from what you have: https://jsfiddle.net/2vqp39nd/ .. Seems like you tried to copy this from some existing site. My guess is it uses javascript to show/hide the menu. Without it, it will not work.

Comment: @brainfeeder 
can't i get a similar of css html vision for my expected menu dropdown? Please post what you have here i have no acess for jsfiddle.net here on my mobile type

Comment: I did not have a solution, just pasted your code there. You might like a menu from https://envato.com/blog/2016/05/14/css-snippets-responsive-menus/ .. Thing is, stackoverflow is for when you get stuck programming, not for asking others to program for you. Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com if you need a responsive CSS framework on your site. All hard work has been done in Bootstrap. It even has navigations and dropdowns.

Comment: Added in code snippet and formatted CSS/HTML. Fixed typos.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to get an effect like the photo attached would be to amend the `.menu ul.active` class giving it:

- `transition: all .5s;` for smooth scrolling
- `overflow:hidden;` so the menu items are hidden when no being toggled
- `height:0px;` to give it a default height of nothing - *important

The I would created a new class called `.drop` and use JavaScript to toggle this new class on and off the `ul`. See both sets of amended code below and here is a JSFiddle link to the working solution - https://jsfiddle.net/2vqp39nd/2/

CSS Changes -

```
.menu ul.active {
    transition: all .5s;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  .drop {
  height:170px!important;
  /* Set this at required height */
}
```

JavaScript Changes -

```
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0],
  btn = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-nav')[0];

  function dropDown () {
        ul.classList.toggle('drop');
    }

  btn.addEventListener('click',dropDown,false);
```

Comment: just wana stay it out from java script just for reson i thought css can save me but all thanks